# What does "y" replace in this prose fragment?

Tags: grammaire

> [J’aurais envie de convoquer la dimension du contretemps, qui me semble
>   traverser *The Black Moon*, et par là je veux évoquer celle de
>   l'impossibilité, ou celle du refus d'abandonner son autonomie, celle
>   de la peur de tomber dans le désir de l'autre, **d'y** être ravie à
>   soi-même, dans un contexte où c'est lui qui la précède - il est
>   curateur avant elle : quand il veut, elle se dérobe,  quand elle veut
>   (à Venise, elle veut deux fois de plus que lui), il feint
>   l'indifférence ou il ne répond pas à son appel, quand il indique la
>   direction, elle ne le suit pas...](http://feministesentousgenres.blogs.nouvelobs.com/archive/2013/07/31/qui-mene-la-danse-entretien-avec-sinziana-ravini-deuxieme-pa.html)

Does *y* in *d'y être ravie à soi-même* of this longer-than-usual quotation replace *la dimension* or *le désir*?

As this is a pretty long fragment of prose, I got lost amongst its many clauses on reading it.

Comment: This question appears to be on-topic but it won't help anyone on the internet. It's too localized.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez "it won't help anyone on the internet": it helps me; ain't that enough? or perhaps I don't count.

Comment: See [the meta discussion](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/467/how-to-deal-with-casual-imperfections-of-texts).

Comment: So this _learning_ site only teaches things that are not _too localized_. What does that even mean? Knowledge is knowledge; it's neither too general nor too localized. Anyway, who came up with this highly unscientific and unpedagogical concept of _localized information_? It really gets in the way of dedicated learners like me who want to check various grammatical rules against all kinds of possible contexts in which they might exist.

Comment: First of all, I would indeed encourage discussion on  [How to deal with casual imperfections of texts?](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/467/how-to-deal-with-casual-imperfections-of-texts)  I think the issue with this particular question is: 1. answering it doesn’t help you (or anyone) understand French better; 2. I’m not sure it has a definitive answer. Now, I think it has its place here because @cl-r answer, which I think really widens its interest. I guess we should try and reformulate the question, though.

Comment: @indoxica, 1/ the place where the policy is discussed is the meta group, not the comments of a question triggering the need to clarify the policy. I purposely won't answer on the policy aspects of your comment. 2/ Grammar rules are not precise enough to say if _y_ refers to _la dimension_ or _le désir_, your question is purely about the meaning of a sentence that most native speakers will find too complex in its form, too obscure in its terms (and that was written by someone who love writing complex sentences).

Comment: J'ai voté **reopen** après avoir écrit une réponse sur la 'meta discussion' au-sujet de la question. Les arguments d' @indoxica sont parfaitement pertinents. La francophonie a aussi beaucoup de textes littéraires, poétiques, des essais et articles innovants qu'il faut encourager à lire et donc a comprendre. Vouloir niveler par le bas, rendre mettre le français au niveau du globish est un affront à l'Autre, le prendre pour un ... imbécile.

Comment: @indoxica: I think you should interpret the downvotes as “this is not the appropriate place to ask such questions”. I know that you could not know this *beforehand*, and that's why I voted to close, instead of downvoting. But now since it is reopened I (and others) have to inform the audience that there is nothing interesting in here. If you want to discuss about “what could the author possibly mean in this obscure sentence”, the best place for this is on the [chat].

Answer (score 3):

My head aches, and I have no freaking idea what the author meant. I must admit that reading this sentence does *not* make me want to read the whole article.

In any case, I would say it refers to *“le désir”*, i.e. “d’être ravie à soi-même dans le désir de l’autre”.

Comment: Un sacré mal de tête, oui! Moi j'ai rien compris du tout...

Comment: tomber où? - .là = dans le désir de l'autre

Answer (score 1):

C'est un exemple de phrase à périodes, forme littéraire utilisée pour décrire l'environnement et les influences d'une situation émotionnelle perçue une première fois.

Elle peut être employée pour saisir ce qui vient à l'esprit avant la formulation du langage qui arrive en flux continu, lorsqu'une intuition, une envie se manifeste.

Il faut donc se référer à la source, au début : l'impulsion ou *l'envie* contribuant au choix d'écriture, le motif ou *la dimension du contretemps* étant le sujet du discours.

Les périodes qui suivent se raccrochent automatiquement à ce dernier, à moins qu'une ou plusieurs imbrications parasites (signalées ici par le `-`) rendent la lecture plus compliquée.

Le *y* se rapporte donc à *la dimension du contretemps*, notion abstraite, vue de l'esprit, mais perçue ici comme pierre de touche, fil conducteur ou architecture d'une œuvre artistique.

**EDIT** *Après nième re-lecture*

Il est toutefois possible de ramener le commencement de la première  "imbrication parasite" à l'absence de *ou* précédent le dernier *celle*, le `-` devenant une nouvelle incise .

Le rythme des phrases à période est souvent ternaire, des trois  se rattachant à la *dimension* et utilisant *celle*, la dernière contient l'amorce du basculement de  la *dimension* convoquée au *désir de l'autre* ; il est donc possible de rattacher *y* à *l'autre* au travers du *désir* que l'on en a, et du jeu trouble qui s'en suit.

Cette orientation ouvre alors la suite du discours, évocation de *l'autre*.

Bien que ce soit probablement là l'intention de l'auteur, le questionnement d'une lecture attentive laisse la possibilité d'un rattachement au 'père' du *désir* ici le *contretemps*.

Comment: J'hésite entre un +1 parce que la réponse expliquant les périodes me plait, et un -1 parce que le _y_ désigne clairement pour moi le désir de l'autre.  En simplifiant un peu la phrase j'ai _Par les termes « la dimension du contretemps » je veux évoquer la dimension de la peur d'être ravie à soi-même [par la plongée] dans le désir de l'autre._

Comment: @Unfrancophone C'est une lecture possible, mais vous oblitérez le mot *convoquer* : l'envie n'est pas l'autre, mais la *convocation* qui laisse un espace de rencontre (avec l'autre) et de dilution de soi par déstabilisation que le contretemps opère sur les repères habituels de l'ego.

Comment: @Unfrancophone J'ai complété ma réponse qui va dans votre sens. Toutefois je reste très sensible à l'interrogation d'Indoxia, (pour des raisons qui sont ici hors de propos), et je reste persuadé que ce genre de question (précise sur des particularités incontournables) fait honneur au site, ne serait-ce que par la qualité des réactions engendrées.

Comment: Je continue de penser qu'il s'agit d'une question portant sur l'interprétation d'un texte plus que sur la langue française, question qui devrait être donc fermée (mais @Jefromi m'a convaincu que "primarily opinion based" est meilleur comme cause), ne fut-ce que parce que le sujet porte à discussion et échange d'arguments et que le format SE s'y prête très mal (en fait il est conçu pour les éviter).

Comment: J'ai retrouvé la référence http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/472/to-the-moderators-of-this-site ; @Unfrancophone en suivant les arguments du modérateur, vous laissez un espace pour le *jeu* : dans le sens qu'un moteur qui n'aurait pas de jeu dans ses mécanisme serait *bloqué* après surchauffe, dans celui du *jeu* de la créativité dans celui des règles du *jeu* de SE, sans les enfreindre ; en restant dans les limites d'usage ... en toute justice le bénéfice du doute à bénéficié à la défense, ce qui honore tout le monde :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, a native would get lost too. I've read the sentence several times and I'm still not completely sure. Ok, let's try this:

> J’aurais envie de convoquer la dimension du contretemps, qui me semble traverser The Black Moon, et par là je veux évoquer celle de l'impossibilité, ou celle du refus d'abandonner son autonomie, celle de la peur de tomber dans le désir de l'autre,

celle = la dimension: *la dimension de l'impossibilité d'abandonner son autonomie, ou la dimension du refus d'abandonner son autonomie, la dimension de la peur de tomber dans le désir de l'autre*

> d'y être ravie à soi-même

I think that *y* reflects to the last concept for which a spatial metaphor was used, namely “*le désir de l'autre*”. It makes some sense: the character is afraid of getting trapped into desire for another, of being consumed by that desire, of being stolen from oneself in that desire, of losing one's individuality.

> dans un contexte où c'est lui qui la précède - il est curateur avant elle : quand il veut, elle se dérobe, quand elle veut (à Venise, elle veut deux fois de plus que lui), il feint l'indifférence ou il ne répond pas à son appel, quand il indique la direction, elle ne le suit pas...

I have even more trouble with that part of the sentence. I think *il* and *elle* are the characters throughout this passage, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Le mot *curateur* me gène, il semble que ce soit un titre universitaire ou honorifique (alors que le petit Robert renvoie seulement à une mise sous curatelle imposée par la Justice). L'article (http://feministesentousgenres.blogs.nouvelobs.com/archive/2013/07/31/qui-mene-la-danse-entretien-avec-sinziana-ravini-deuxieme-pa.html), renvoie *il* et *elle* aux premiers rôles d'un film qui se veux "film-exhibition", d'où l'impression de naviguer dans l'inconnu à la lecture de cet article

Comment: @cl-r Ça pourrait aussi être l'adjectif [curateur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/curateur) : il soulage, il guérit. Mais ça ne me paraît pas très cohérent avec le reste du passage (oui, bon, parler de cohérence pour ce passage, c'est osé). Donc je pense qu'il faut s'accrocher à l'étymologie : le mot latin *curator* (gardien).

Comment: tomber où? - Là = dans le désir de l'autre. Le Y reprend ce là = dans le désir de l'autre.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it refers to « la dimension de la peur ».

Which could be explicitly used like this :

> la dimension de la peur de tomber dans le désir de l'autre, la dimension de la peur d'y être ravie à soi-même.

But like other French people above, I'm far from sure.